# Sticking footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm try to get my footer to stick to the bottom of the page on this website: https://account.radonsystems.net.

Unfortunately, it seems not to be working, though it is working everywhere else I've used it.

This is the CSS for the sticky:

```
html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
padding-bottom: 57px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
margin-top: -57px; /* negative value of footer height */
height: 35px;
clear:both;}

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/
}    

.footer a,.footer a:hover{text-decoration:underline;color:#FFF;}
```

Does anyone have any idea of why it's not sticking to the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works everywhere else, then something must be wrong with that html page, not the CSS, maybe post the HTML page code, or compare it to those that actually work correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I can tell you a better option to fix it at the bottom

Just apply style as

```
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:57px;
}
```

Thanks and regards,

**Wazzy**

Comment: If I am not wrong, your css will hide the footer since it will start paint it in bottom=0. Instead, there should be: bottom:HEIGHT_OF_FOOTER;.

Comment: @Naor That's not how 'bottom' works. Specifying 'bottom:0' means the *bottom* of the element is aligned with the bottom of the viewport, in the same way as specifying 'right:0' means the right edge of the element aligns with the right edge of the viewport.  You describe what would happen if someone specified 'top:100%'.

Comment: I believe the 'width:100%' part is superfluous since you already said 'left:0; right:0;' but no harm done!

Answer (score 0):

Look over the [sticky footer tutorial](http://www.htmltutorialsandtips.com/css-sticky-footer) at this link to see how the sticky footer concept works. This should help you be able to compare your html structure and css to find the problem. If you can give us your html we can look at it with you.